# How to generate all possible combos of a matrix - Letter Soup game

Tags: c

I'm working on a little letter soup game and i need help to figure out how to make this.

I want to build a script to print all the possible words a soup could generate. Imagine i have the soup

```
ABC
DEF
```

The game allows the user to navigate to the 8 positions around the letter he is in. If the user where to start on letter "B", he could chose any of the other letters on the matrix.

User can't use a letter on a position he visited already. So, using the example above, i could make the word ABF but not the word ABA.

I have words that are prefix of other words. For example AB is word and ABC is word too.

In the example above, we have a 2x3 matrix but words can have 23 letters length so i need to figure out words of a max 23 letters for big matrix.

I don't even know where to begin from... I have code to see if a generated word is valid or not. I have one that sees if the word is part of a word so I wouldn´t continue to check if it's not... But I can't figure how to build words to 8 different positions around the 1º letter...

Can you give me a little help to figure this out?

Comment: It seems to me that this could be modelled as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), where each letter is a node and is connected to 'adjacent' letters. There are algorithms (Ie, [Depth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) to find all unique paths so then you could apply that.

Comment: Hmm... Doing a struct maybe and doing linked listings for the words? That would be a way to do it... but how would i store that info for all the matrix?

Comment: That's a fairly typical computer science problem, you can look up other Undirected-Graph implementations in C for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `node` struct that represents a position in the matrix, with one of its elements being a `node*[8]` or `node**` to represent the available paths out of the node. Each node needs a `char value` to tell you what it is labelled by. They also need a `int traversed` which I'll talk about later.

[Here](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.ca/2013/09/graphs.html) is a discussion on graphs in C instead using an adjacency matrix (a bit more efficient).

The path that they generate will basically be a string of the `char value` that are traversed. Since you know that you can only have `n * m` total unique paths in this, you can just make a fixed size `char* path` that is no more than `n * m + 1` characters (the last one is for `\0`, of course).

Perform a [Depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the graph you have constructed starting from each of the nodes, creating a list of all possible `char*` paths. Make sure that in the DFS you mark each node that you hit as `traversed = 1` so that you don't repeat any (and of course if you hit a `traversed == 1` node just stop that particular path). Very important that you reset all the nodes to `traversed = 0` after you're done with them.

Comment: Ok i got a good idea of what to do. Let's see if i can translate it to code :P

Thank you :)